Change font (family/size/color) when filling out a PDF in Preview
This should be a duplicate of Change font size for PDF Text Annotation in Preview, but the answers there do not apply. Under Sequoia, with Preview v11.0, I am filling out a PDF. I have added a text box. I cannot find any way to change the font used in that text box. The screenshot below includes the Tips app showing where there SHOULD be controls for adjusting the font, abut as shown at the top no controls are visible.
How can I adjust the font for text I'm adding as an annotation?


As shown in my screenshot, I had the "Form Filling Toolbar" active, which (oddly) does not have these controls (despite letting you create new text boxes).

Switching to the Markup Toolbar shows the font controls I needed:

The answer became obvious only after I posted the question, and really looked at what was highlighted in the Tips screenshot.
